# Mysql returning only on row with group by query when multiple exist

Tags: php, mysql

i have a mysql table as such

id,row1,row2,row3

and i have entries like

```
ID  | row1   | row2     | row3
-------------------------------
 1  |   10   |    5    | 10
 2  |   20   |    5    | 10
```

and when i run a sql like this

```
SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE row3 = 10 GROUP BY row2
```

it only returns one row. i want it to return both rows.

Any help would be appreciated guys

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE row3 = 10 GROUP BY row2
```

the **GROUP BY row2** tells it to take all rows where **row2**'s value is the same and display them together (a summary entry).

If you want to see all the rows, remove the GROUP BY command

```
SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE row3 = 10
```

Comment: ya, i want it to get all the rows with row 3 as 10 and group both the similar values of row2 and display it in two rows

Comment: @user1690718, I am not exactly following the problem

Comment: i want to select all the rows where the row2 value is same as the value indicated by where clause                                                 where -> check value then choose all the rows with same value as row2 from the result of where clause

Comment: Could you add one more row to your example? Make sure it has `row3` with a value *not* equal to 10. Also add what you expect to see when your query is run against the three rows. If you do that I bet you'll have an answer in no time.

Comment: Might be still misunderstanding, but may be you are talking about ORDER, not GROUP. Have you tried SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE row3 = 10 ORDER BY row2. If not, I don't think it is possible to return results as multidimensional array with 2 or more subsets of rows straight in sql

Comment: Please show what the results you are looking for should look like

Answer (score 0):

Run your original SELECT query without the GROUP BY at all. After that loop through the results in PHP and use another SELECT QUERY such as

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE row2=" . $resultrow['row2']
```